# Having Apache access to multiple folders in Windows Server 2008

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, virtualhost, httpd, windows

I am modifying an existing Apache setup on a Windows machine to allow access to multiple directories and have hit a small obstacle due to confusion. I have the main root directory in which the web site is hosted on. The other 2 directories are archives of images and documents that the user can have access, browse through, and download. I've looked through some online documentation and was a bit confused on whether I can just add some directories to the httpd.conf file or if I actually have to create virtual hosts. Any help or a point in the proper direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you don't currently have any virtual hosts setup in your http.conf file.  In that case, you should add the directories to your http.conf file.

If your folders are stored outside of your document root (like on separate disks), then create an alias for the folder:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Simplifed explanation of name-based virtual hosts: 
Virtual hosts are a way of having one webserver serve multiple domains.  A normal practice is to have the http.conf include directories that will contain additional apache configuration information.  To keep future growth as an option, many people will only define virtual hosts in separate files stored in these included directories.  In this way, if they want to add a second domain (or a subdomain) in the future, all they do is create another vhost file and save it to the included directory.

Comment: How would I access the additional directories? If the Document root is in "C/www" and I have a directory with "C/www", "F/Images", and "H/Files" how would I access the F and H directory? The webpage can be accessed easily on the machine through "localhost\index.html".

Comment: Use an alias (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).